# Catch custom Exception that is raised by a function inside the try-block

Tags: python

I've been trying to catch an exception that should be caused by clicking a hotkey, unfortunately adding a hotkey requires to add a function that should be called when said hotkey is pressed.

Now I know that exceptions will only be caught if they're raised inside the `try-catch` block, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
class resetException(Exception): pass

try:
    def resetRun(event):
        raise resetException

    Env.addHotkey(resetKey, 0, resetRun)

    while True:
        [...]
except resetException:
    popup("reset")
```

The exception is raised, but it seems like it isn't raised inside the try-block? If I just raise the `resetException` without the function, this works perfectly fine.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-8" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sikuli\sikulix.jar\Lib\sikuli\Env.py", line 13, in hotkeyPressed
  File "Sikuli\Test.sikuli\Test.py", line 339, in resetRun
    raise resetException
__main__.resetException
```

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this multi-threaded? (seems like your binding keys, so I'm guessing you have an event-loop active)

Comment: Take out exception function out of try..catch block

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `def` with `try/catch`? Move it inside of the `def`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like it is. I don't know if it helps, but everytime I press the hotkey, the thread in the traceback increases by 1 (`"Thread-8"`, `"Thread-9"`, `"Thread-10"`, ...)

Comment: @FullName I was trying to wrap the while-loop with the try/catch

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're out of the main thread's context. This is a multi-threaded environment which is hinted by you binding keys to callbacks.

There is probably an eventloop with a thread (or threads) waiting to handle your key callbacks once a user presses a key.

What you need to do is put the try-catch inside the `resetRun` so that the thread actually executing the code (which is calling your callback) can handle the exception.

You could create a wrapper like this:

```
def with_try_catch(f):
    def wrapped():
        try:
            f()
        catch YourException:
            # handle exception
    return wrapped
```

Now bind like this:

```
Env.addHotkey(resetKey, 0, with_try_catch(resetRun))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the exception inside your function doesn't raised at **run-time**. The fact is that a [`try-except` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) will catch the exceptions in run-time, for example:

```
>>> try:
...     def a():
...        raise ValueError
...     a()
... except ValueError:
...     print('The exception is caught')
... 
The exception caught
```

And in this case it seems that you are just instantiating an object or smth. (your function is not executed at run-time)

```
Env.addHotkey(resetKey, 0, resetRun)
```

Which means that the exceptions will raise after compile time (when you use that function), in this case, when you push the button.

So if you want to handle the exception inside the function you need to catch them inside the function.

Answer (score -1):

I am no expert, but it seems to me that the problem is your `def resetRun(event)` bit. The `try...except` instruction set cannot dig into a function definition. What happens if you create resetRun(event) outside of `try...except`? Does it work then?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything at all. I don't think that could work anyways, since the `raise` must happen inside the try/catch block?